# Ninja Forms Custom Textfield with pre-set Field Key

Tags: php, wordpress, ninja-forms

Is there any way you can create a custom text field template with ninja form where u can set your own field key for it? so you can just select the field and put it in your form without having to adjust the field key?

We have found following two links so far:
https://developer.ninjaforms.com/codex/custom-field-templates/
http://developer.ninjaforms.com/codex/field-templates/

but there is no documentation or solution on how to add your own field keys to it.

Has anyone worked with this before or has an idea on how to achieve this?

Thanks a lot for any response!